# OpenGL enumerating graphic cards

Tags: opengl-3

OpenGL 3.3 is not supported by all graphic video cards. On my pc i have 2 graphic cards, one basic Intel video card, and one ATI Radeon. Only Radeon supports OGL 3 or higher, but my default card is the Intel one, so when an application starts, as defualt its started on Intel adapter.

I am trying to write a software using OpenGL 3.3, how can i choose runtime in my software, on wich card to get OpenGL context?

Comment: Which operating system are you using?  Control of the active graphics device is usually something you specify in an OS control panel.  OpenGL itself doesn't know about devices when creating a context; it gets that information from the window or device that you create in the native OS.

Comment: to have a video initialization similar to Direct3D i should use operating system's functions, OpenGL just get what the system offer... that will make it a bit ugly

Comment: Sorry, I'm not much of a Microsoft Windows programmer.  However, as I understand it, an OpenGL context inherits some of its properties (e.g., bits/component, etc.) from the hDC passed into `wglCreateContext` (or similar functions).  So, I think you can choose your graphics adapter when you create the hDC.  There's probably something in [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/) that might help.  Sorry I can't be more informative.

Comment: yes, you are right. i will need to spend some time on MSDN to find out a way. now i understand why this is not possible from opengl, its clear, i even dont understand how i didnt see it before.